# What type of provider is SDS in ArcGIS Enterprise

Tags: arcgis-enterprise

Can someone tell me what the SDS provider in ArcGIS Enterprise is?

[image]

Comment: the virtual directory defined when the SDS was installed. 'arcgis' is the default value https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/sds/rest/gettingstarted.html

Comment: ArcGIS Spatial Data Server (SDS) was a single-release product at 10.1, Esri deprecated it by ArcGIS 10.2 when ArcGIS Server's feature access capability was expanded to support non-geodatabase databases.  I can't imagine you are seeing that in the wild these days.

Comment: Thanks for reply bixb0012, we are using ArcGIS Enterprise 10.9.1 (started from 10.6.1). Running ArcGIS Python for API to get our services `Provider` I am getting more than 130 services in SDS format! so for sure this must be something else! is Hosted services using same `ArcGIS Spatial Data Server (SDS)` technology?